# WebStorm console.log(arguments) breaks node debugger

Tags: webstorm, node-debugger

While debugging in WebStorm (2016.1), the debugger breaks after `console.log(arguments)`. Here's an example:

```
function breakDebug() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

breakDebug();

console.log("still kickin'");  // WS will not stop on breakpoint here
```

This can be solved by converting `arguments` to some type that won't choke debugger (`array`, `object` or whatever) on the caller side, something like this:

```
function digestible(args) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(args);
}

function breakDebug() {
    console.log(digestible(arguments)); // this is cumbersome
}

breakDebug();

console.log("still kickin'"); // this time debugger stops
                              // on breakpoint here
```

Instead of explicitly converting arguments to array, is there some safe voodoo that could be performed over `console` object that would make the first snippet not break the debugger? By safe I mean compliant to all the best practices a JS n00b like me doesn't know about.

As a side question, should I report this to JetBrains?

Comment: We had no luck reproducing the issue with Node.js v4 and v5... Would be great if you file a more detailed bug report on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB Thank you!

Comment: I reported it already, and got this ticket by email: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20235. I'll add more info there.

Comment: Here's the permalink to additional info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20235#comment=27-1356952

Comment: Thank you! Hope the issue will be resolved soon.

Comment: any update on this issue. I am facing same kind of issue.